# SAS - how to mask double quotes (e.g. "")

Tags: vba, sas

I am running a VBA program from SAS. The SAS code for this basically looks like:

```
%let worksheet =&i; *worksheet number;
%let xlsfile = %STR(""C:\Data\Excel Workbook.xlsx"");
%let csvfile = %STR(""C:\Data\CSV File..csv"");


x 'cd "C:\Data\MN2013\Alignment\Data\SAS Programs"';
x "XlsWsToCsv.vbs &xlsfile &worksheet &csvfile";
```

I need to be able to include two double quotes (i.e. "") at the beginning and end of the file paths in the xlsfile and csvfile for the VBA program to recognize the spaces in the file paths and run correctly.

#### MY PROBLEM:

I run this in SAS Enterprise Guide using SAS 9.3. In my log, directly after the variable definition is read in, the double quotes are underlined in red (usually indicating an error) with the number 49 below. There is no error message, but instead, in green I get the following note:

```
NOTE 49-169: The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a future SAS 
         release.  Inserting white space between a quoted string and the succeeding 
         identifier is recommended.
```

To me, this says SAS is reading these double quotes. They are somehow only partially being masked. My VBA program runs, so I could continue with this; but I like clean error logs. Does anyone have any recommendations for how to completely mask my xlsfile and csvfile variables? I've tried using %STR (as shown in my example above), %BQUOTE, %SUPERQ, and a few other things to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those pesky error messages!  You were very close, but try this syntax instead:

```
%let xlsfile = %STR("")C:\Data\Excel Workbook.xlsx%STR("");
%let csvfile = %STR("")C:\Data\CSV File..csv%STR("");
```

Answer (score 2):

Double double quotes inside double quotes resolve to a single double quote character, ie...

```
x """c:\program files\office\excel.exe"" stuff stuff stuff ""stuff"" stuff";
```

should work just fine.  Don't worry about the 'identifier' message, that's largely saying something like

```
"01JAN2013"d
```

could be possible with other things.  You can add a space after the last " if it's a problem to have that in the log.

Comment: Where can I add a space? After any use of double double quotes or at the end of my variable definition (e.g., %let xlsfile = %STR("" C:\Data\Excel Workbook.xlsx"" ); VS %let xlsfile = %STR(""C:\Data\Excel Workbook.xlsx"" );)? The first one won't work because then my file path includes a space at the beginning and VBA won't recognize it. The second one is giving me the same 'Note' that I started with...  I would like to be able to eliminate this message so I can rely on Enterprise Guide's quick error identifier (a little icon which displays over the filename) which is currently getting tripped.